# Thermal printer ESC/POS status command result to BASH variable

Tags: bash, thermal-printer, escpos

I am trying to create a script that will check if the serial connection is functional on the thin client running strip down version of ubuntu.

I am able to print to the printer, however, I need to find a way to read settings from the printer connected with RS232 (ttyS0).

here is the BASH script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Gather information
ip4=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
locdate=$(date)
drstatus="To be implemented yet"
#[Set serial port speed]
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 38400;
#listen to the port report
# cat /dev/ttyS0&
#[Send print test to the printer]
#initialize printer
echo -e '\x1b\x40'>/dev/ttyS0
# send printer data
echo -e '\x1b\x45 TM88 Hardware Test:\x1b\x46\xa'>/dev/ttyS0
echo -e $locdate'' >/dev/ttyS0
echo -e 'Hostname: '$HOSTNAME'' >/dev/ttyS0
echo -e 'Endpoint IP address: '$ip4''>/dev/ttyS0
echo -e '\x1d\x6b\x04000\x00'>/dev/ttyS0
echo -e 'Printer connected to COM1 / ttyS0'>/dev/ttyS0
echo -e 'Comm. speed 38400 bps'>/dev/ttyS0
echo -e 'Cash drawer status:'$drstatus'\xa'>/dev/ttyS0
echo -e '\xa\xa\xa\xa\xa\xa\x1bm'>/dev/ttyS0
```

According to the [reference site](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=124#gs_lr) the code should look like this for the request should look like this:

```
echo -e '\x1d\x49\x01'>/dev/ttyS0
```

and the response should be visible with

```
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

However cat does not display anything.

How can I get the response from the ESC/POS command into a variable?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: maybe your printer is connected to ttyS1?

Comment: Nope. it is on COM1(ttyS0), and prints commands sent to ttyS0. All of the code is functional, but missing a way to read responses from the printer. There are two console sessions, one sending commands, and other running cat.

Comment: The command you are sending is here [GS I](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=198), not the page you are referring to. Depending on the printer model, it may not be notified, and the data that is notified may not be printable as text, so please check the detailed specifications of the printer you are using.

Comment: By the way, wouldn't the separate redirection of separate command executions by bash involve opening/closing files? Even if the printer is sending data, wouldn't the device driver's buffer be cleared once it's closed/reopened? You might want to look into the details of how bash commands and device drivers behave.

Comment: For example, try sending a similar command with terminal software such as minicom instead of bash and see if you can receive data. However, you will need to be able to display the incoming data as binary data rather than text. If you can see the received data, it means that you can't separate the sending and receiving with a bash script and use separate commands. If you don't see the received data, something might be wrong, such as sending the wrong command.